# Why does my protobuf-net stream not work?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have  an object that can be serialized and deserialized but upon deserialization it throws me an error:

`Invalid field in source data: 0`

I don't know why this is happening

**code for de-serialization and receiving:**

```
public void listenUDP()
{
        EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)groupEP;
        //BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        recieving_socket.Bind(ep);
        while (true)
        {

            byte[] objData = new byte[65535];
            recieving_socket.ReceiveFrom(objData, ref ep);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(objData, 0, objData.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            messageHandle(ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<SimplePacket>(ms));
            ms.Dispose();


        }
    }
```

**Code for serialization:**

```
public void sendDataUDP(Vec2f[] data)
    {

            SimplePacket packet = new SimplePacket(DateTime.UtcNow, data);
            //IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch st = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            //formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<SimplePacket>(stream, packet);
            //Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedTicks);
            stream.Close();
            st.Restart();
            sending_socket.SendTo(stream.ToArray(), sending_end_point);
            //Console.WriteLine(st.ElapsedTicks);
            st.Stop();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root object in a protobuf message, as defined by the google specification, does not include any notion of the **end** of the message. This is intentional, so that concatenation is identical to merging two fragments. Consequently, the consuming code needs to restrict itself to a single message. This is identical between all protobuf implementations, and is not specific for protobuf-net.

What is happening is that your buffer is currently oversized, with garbage at the end. **Currently** (because you are reading one message) that garbage is most likely all zeros, and a zero is not a valid marker for a field. However, when re-using the buffer the garbage could be... anything.

In your case, probably the easiest way to do this is to use the `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` / `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` methods, which handle all this for you by prepending the payload length at the start of the message, and only processing that much data.

As a final thought: it is not clear to me that your code will guarantee that is has read an *entire* message; a single receive could (on TCP, at least) return part of a message - or 2 and a bit messages, etc: TCP is stream-based, not message-based.